# Series and characteristc function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, characteristic-functions

> **Problem:** Graph the following functions and formally justifying your answer.
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\chi_{[n,+\infty)} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\chi_{[0,n]}
> \end{eqnarray*}

**My approach:** By definition, we know that if si $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, eso **characteristic function** of $E$ let's to define as $$\chi_{E}(x):=\left\{ \begin{aligned} 1, \quad x \in E\\ 0, \quad x\notin E\end{aligned} \right.$$
Then, by definition we can see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\chi_{[n,+\infty)}(x)=\left\{ \begin{aligned} 1, \quad x \in [n, +\infty)\\ 0, \quad x \notin [n,+\infty) \end{aligned}\right. \quad \text{y} \quad \chi_{[0,n]}(x)=\left\{ \begin{aligned} 1, \quad x \in [0, n]\\ 0, \quad x \notin [0,n] \end{aligned}\right. 
\end{eqnarray*}
So,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\chi_{[n,+\infty)}(x)=\chi_{[1,+\infty)}(x)+\chi_{[2,+\infty)}(x)+\chi_{[3,+\infty)}(x)+\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}(x)+\chi_{[0,2]}(x)+\chi_{[0,3]}(x)\cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}

---

*But, I don't know how to continue. How can I grah that functions?*
*Is there another approach for to solve this problem?*
Thank you!

Comment: The first function is the greatest integer function and the second one is $\infty$ at every point of $[0,\infty)$

Comment: How can I see that statements? I can see it geometrically, but I don't know how can I justify that. Can you explain more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a plot of the function
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\chi_{[n,+\infty)}(x)$$
[image]

Comment: can you explain me how do you obtain the second graph?

Comment: @Ramanujan I realized that makes little sense so I deleted that grapf. In my opinion the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)$$ diverges  for any $x$.

Comment: Ok, Thank  you! I understand.